# How to draw a partial border？

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer

Just as the following image,  how to draw that black line?
I want the line to be drawn on layer, not on another view.
The problem I got is how to locate the bottom. Thanks for any suggestion.
[image]

Comment: Simply use a UIView

Comment: Calc the bottom by adding the height of the view to the origin.y of the view.

Comment: @user6788419 Yes, that's the solution I'm using now. I just wonder how to know implement it via Layer.

Comment: @BencePattogato But the height is unknown until AutoLayout set the constrains.

Answer (score 0):

Here i have used textfield same way you can use for button also

```
let borderOld = CALayer()

let width = CGFloat(1.5)

borderOld.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: txtField.frame.size.height - width, width:  txtField.frame.size.width, height: txtField.frame.size.height)
borderOld.borderWidth = width

txtField.layer.masksToBounds = true

txtField.layer.addSublayer(borderOld)
```

Comment: But I use AutoLayout to constrain the view. So the frame is not the final frame.